# Android.mk seems not to exist

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I hope I have not overseen the question was already asked or the question is to stupid...

I have installed Android Studio and Android NDK following the official tutorial at http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html and I could run the simple hello-jni app on my device. In the tutorial in the following "building section" is told that "The Android.mk file resides in a subdirectory of your project's jni/" but I am absolute sure, that there is no Android.mk in my project -.-

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch!

The Android.mk file belongs to the old times. Android Studio moves into easier integration of NDK, and you don't need to run `ndk-build` anymore. Unfortunately, NDK support in Android Studio is still not final; the description at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview is not exactly up-to-date, and another, "experimental" plugin is under development, sa described here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Comment: Thanks!

But I somehow feel a little bit betrayed. The download site of android studio states 2.0 is the actual version and I read everywhere that NDK support is preview only until 1.3, so I though it would be stable now.

And I am not happy that the official tutorial at http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html is "lying" about such basic things...

Comment: So there are many changes for the NDK expected soon? That is bad for me, because I am supposed to use it for my master project this semester. Maybe some good reading suggestions for me to getting started like http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview? (Because the official tutorial seems not to be a good starting point right now :( ) ( Or is this supposed to be an own question, or not a good question for stackoverflow at all? )

Comment: If you need basic NDK support as described in at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview, then I would suggest to use AS 2.0 with the official Gradle plugin. If that's not enough, for a master project you can pick up the latest experimental plugin and tune your configuration as described at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental. For commercial product, I'd probably recommend to use the old-style **ndk-build** setup, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36651488/192373

Comment: thanks again! Probably it is a good thing to learn Gradle anyway :) So I will do some broad tutorial stuff and try my luck during the semester... :-P