# Is there no Android.mk anymore in android build system?

Tags: android, android-studio, android.mk

I last worked on Android application development some while back(on Gingerbread). I came back to it again now.

I have inherited a sample hello-jni project into Android studio. But, there is no Android.mk and I see gradle instead. Is it a new build system and is Android.mk not used anymore?

Comment: android studio is using gradle now, yes.

Comment: @quidproquo From when did this change happen? Through out android code, I can see so man yAndroid.mk files still.

Comment: you can check out the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754643/what-is-gradle-in-android-studio). You can still configure your own build system with ant if you wish

Comment: More about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630091/android-mk-seems-not-to-exist

Answer (score 0):

Android.mk is used only when you need to implement NDK in Android Otherwise its not needed to build the project.

Comment: Hello-JNI uses NDK right? Even it is not present here.